# EXTREME beginner making a website from scratch, how do i center things, pictures, and zoom problems

Tags: css, html

I've added an image that I want to be a banner for my website. http://puu.sh/peaj0/f753d03c5b.png

However, when I zoom in to 100%, it looks like this:
http://puu.sh/pealY/7c11f8c9d1.png

Why does it do this and how do I make it so at 100% zoom, it is perfectly centered? This is my css for it:

```
.Banner {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

How does choosing a very large picture affect this? And would it be possible to scale it down to a smaller size with only css?

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Would you be able to provide some HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest making it the `background-image` of your element with `background-size: cover;` and `background-position: center center;`. It will work with any image and will always be centered and filled.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner {
  background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/2048x2048?text=Banner);
  height: 250px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  background: #aaa;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="banner"></div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Unternehmen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Produkte</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Galerie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I want to use the image as a banner. I was trying to replicate a website that looked like this: http://puu.sh/pebTM/ccbba6c2b4.png.

Comment: @Simon2233 I just updated it to make it look like your example. If this works for you, could you select it as correct?

Comment: Here is what it looks like with your code, seems like the width of the picture doesn't match the navigation bar. http://puu.sh/pefyn/eac6e723db.png. I also want to ask, what changes did u make so that when i opened my html file, it was already zoomed at 100%?

Comment: Make sure that you aren't putting an `<img />` tag anywhere. You should reference the image from the css `url()`. Could I see your html?

Comment: Oh, yes i've been using the <img> tag, heres my html: http://puu.sh/pejQY/6353fae50e.png. Whats the difference between using background-img url vs img?

Comment: Adding it as `background-image: url();` allows you to set the properties `background-size` and `background-position`. To do the same with `<img />` requires Javascript. The `background-image` is just easier to do. So you would need to remove the `<img />` tag and copy that url into the css file where I had the `url()`

Comment: I see thanks so much. One last question. How was it made so that the banner and navigation bar didn't take up the whole page from left to right, like here: http://www.tecloga.de/index.html. The html you made took up the whole space: http://puu.sh/pekIT/5d919bf7b4.png. Also, if i were to get a bigger picture, how could i make it smaller so it would fit the same amount of size as the smaller picture I have now?

Comment: No problem. I have edited the snippet above to have a wrapper which limits the size. To make it the size of your image, I would just say hardcode the width into the `max-width` property in the css ( I just added that above )

Comment: Great! I tried changing the body margin to ?px and it worked as well. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Of course! It's always hard when you first start, but you'll be doing this from memory in no time! Keep working.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to use `display: block;` on the image.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0u53qx2/) out.

#### HTML

```
<div>
  <img src="http://payload272.cargocollective.com/1/3/114820/7754510/ALS-LOGO-01-01_1200.png" alt="">
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: img would make it apply to all <img> tags right? If i were to have more i could use div img {}. correct me if im wrong!

Comment: @Simon2233 You can set a class for all of the images you want the style to apply to and leave the others using their default styles.

Comment: This is good, but I don't think this will behave like a banner. It would have to have the same ratio of the banner. But that can always change.